# Strange errors and outputs in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code in Scala:

```
var i: Int = 0
var sum: Int = 0

for(i<- 1 to 10)
{
    sum= sum+1  
}
println(sum)
```

Although it is elementary I noticed that if you write

```
sum=-sum+1
```

it produces an error.

Also if you write

```
sum=-(sum+1)
```

it produces an error too and

```
sum= -(sum+1)
```

produces zero. Why zero?

This doesn't happen in C++ for instance and I found it odd. What is happening and why? Does it matter if you use spaces in Scala?

Comment: What error is your code producing?

Comment: @egracer one of then is "value =- is not a member of Double".

Comment: You repeat `sum= -(sum+1)` 10 times. So sum changes as 0 -> -1 -> 0 -> -1 and so on and ends up being 0.

Comment: @Adam my answer below is the problem then. The compiler thinks `=-` should be an operator on `Double`, but there is no such operator defined in the API.

Comment: @egracer that doesn't explain the third case. When I use a space so there isn't this operator =-  why the result is zero?

Comment: @Kolmar has the answer for your about the third case. `sum` starts at `0`, then becomes `-(0+1) = -1`.  Then `sum` is `-1`, and `-(-1+1)`. You just alternate back and forth between the two.

Comment: @egracer I hadn't  see Kolmar's comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first two cases, the Scala compiler is likely interpreting `=-` as an operator, instead of associating the `-` with the right-hand side of the assignment. The third case was answered in the comments.